# React native not initializing ReactCoundownClock

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to run a simple example with the ReactCountdownClock. But it is not able to initialize.

The setup is as following:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {ReactCountdownClock} from 'react-countdown-clock';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myCallback = this.myCallback.bind(this);
  }
  myCallback() {
    console.log("test");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        
        <ReactCountdownClock seconds={60}
                     color="#000"
                     alpha={0.9}
                     size={300}
                     onComplete={this.myCallback} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

But I just keep getting an Element type is invalid:  Expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file its defined in.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I assume from the coffee-script code on the [components Github](https://github.com/pughpugh/react-countdown-clock/blob/master/coffee/react-countdown-clock.coffee) page, you don't have to use the curly brackets on the import. So instead of using

```
import { ReactContdownClock } from 'react-countdown-clock';
```

you could write

```
import ReactContdownClock from 'react-countdown-clock';
```

cause there is just that single exported component.

But as far as I understand React-Native you will run into a second issue because this component uses (renders) HTML Tags and these will not be displayed until they're rendered by a WebView.